# MIPS 32 always stores 10 mul and li in $t

Tags: mips, cpu-registers, temporary, mips32, qtspim

This is part of my code, and I don't know why, $t1 always ends up with 10, when it should be 16. At this point, the data is the following:

```
$t5 = 4
$t3 = 1
$t2 = 0
and $t1 is 0
(and $t0 is an address)
```

This is the part of the code:

```
mul $t1, $t3 , $t5
add $t1, $t1, $t2
mul $t1, $t1, 4
**From here, $t1 should be 16, but it always turns out 10 even if I do li $t1, 16****
add $t1, $t1, $t0
lw $t6, ($t1)
```

I'm using MIPS 32 with QTSpim

Comment: It's 10 according to what..? Maybe what you're looking at is the value displayed in hex? (10 hexadecimal is 16 decimal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set registers->Decimal, the result will be 16. I guess, going from the information you give.

[image]